# Get element at index of a Array[(Array[String, Long)]

Tags: scala

So I have some data:

```
val data = Array[(Array[String], Long)]
```

Which is an array of pairs, where each pair consists of another array and a number. I have created a ListBuffer as follows:

```
var x = ListBuffer[(Array[String], Long)]
```

I would like to append an element at some index `i` to `x`. I do the following:

```
 x += data(i)
```

However, I get the error:

> Type mismatch, expected: String, actual: (Array[String], Long)

What am I doing wrong? I am working in IntelliJ and Scala 2.10.7.

Also this example (which is a concrete example (I cannot provide the original example)) also gives the same error:

```
val xData = ListBuffer[(Array[String], Long)]
    var x = ListBuffer[(Array[String], Long)]
    x += xData(0)
```

Comment: Could you please provide a complete example?

Comment: I added a different example, but same error, it is concrete

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the issue was that I forgot brackets at the end of ListBuffer initiation.

This works:

```
var x = ListBuffer[(Array[String], Long)]()
```

Comment: you can't assign dataTypes to variables?

Comment: What do you mean?

Comment: `ListBuffer[(Array[String], Long)]` is definition of datatypes and you can't assign datatypes as you did. you can define datatypes using `:` as `var x: ListBuffer[(Array[String], Long)] = actual value`

Answer (score 1):

I have tried the same thing in scala REPL just now, and it is working fine.

What I did is -

```
    scala> val arr = Array("Hello", "Bye")
    arr: Array[String] = Array(Hello, Bye)

    scala> var data = Array((arr,1), (arr,2))
    data: Array[(Array[String], Int)] = Array((Array(Hello, Bye),1), 
    (Array(Hello, Bye),2))

    scala> import scala.collection.mutable.ListBuffer
    import scala.collection.mutable.ListBuffer


    scala> val list = ListBuffer((arr, 1))
    list: scala.collection.mutable.ListBuffer[(Array[String], Int)] = 
    ListBuffer((Array(Hello, Bye),1))


    scala> list += data(0)
    res1: list.type = ListBuffer((Array(Hello, Bye),1), (Array(Hello, 
    Bye),1))
```

It did not give any error

Comment: Hmm, it's odd, can it be because I never specified how Array[String] should be?

Comment: I cant make an array and use it to create a ListBuffer, it says it doesnt know what the array is. So even your example is broken

Comment: There must be some problem in the way you are creating the variables.